# Strange problem with variable in C program

Tags: c

This code is to change decimal "n" to binary that I wrote like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
    char str[] = "";
    int a = 5;
    int n = 5;
    while(n > 0){
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            strcat(str,"0");
        } else {
            strcat(str, "1");
        }
        n = n / 2;
    }
    strrev(str);

    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem here is, when I tried to debug and see the variable changing, the "a" changed in a very strange way, although I don't do anything to "a". Why is it like that?

Comment: Probably because you overwrote the end of `str` and modified the *next* variable on the stack. Allocate enough space for `str`.

Comment: Your `str` is an object capable of holding **only the empty string**. If you want it to hold a string of 3 characters (like `"foo"`) you need to define as `char str[4] = "";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array `str`, because it doesn't have an explicit size, is sized to exactly store what it is initialized with.  And because an empty string only contains 1 character, namely a terminating null byte, your array is 1 element in size.

This means `str` isn't large enough to hold any string that's not an empty string, so using `strcat` on it causes the function to write past the end of the array, triggering [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  In this case, it manifests as writing into another variable which happens to be adjacent to the array in memory.

The array must be sized properly to hold whatever string it might hold, i.e.:

```
char str[33] = "";
```

This gives you enough space to store the binary representation of any nonnegative 32 bit integer.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> char str[] = "";
> ```

Since there's no explicit length given, the array is given the length of the `""` initializer, which contains a single `\0` character. This declaration is equivalent to:

```
char str[1] = {'\0'};
```

There is no space reserved for additional characters. When you do `strcat(str,...)` it writes past the end of the array and triggers undefined behavior.

You can fix this by allocating extra space:

```
char str[100] = "";
```

Or if you don't like an arbitrary `100` and want the exact size that can handle all numbers:

```
char str[sizeof n * CHAR_BIT + 1] = "";
```